# Computed property on a service that accesses the store

Tags: ember.js, promise, ember-data

I wrote a service for loading notifications:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Service.extend({
  sessionUser: Ember.inject.service(),
  store: Ember.inject.service(),

  read() {
    let currentUserId = this.get('sessionUser.user.id');
    return this.get('store').query('notification', {
      userId: currentUserId,
      read: true
    });
  },

  unread() {
    let currentUserId = this.get('sessionUser.user.id');
    return this.get('store').query('notification', {
      userId: currentUserId,
      read: false
    });
  }
});
```

I want to change the colour of an icon in the navigation bar when there are unread notifications. The navigation bar is a component:

```
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({
  notifications: Ember.inject.service(),
  session: Ember.inject.service(),

  hasUnreadNotifications: Ember.computed('notifications', function() {
    return this.get('notifications').unread().then((unread) => {
      return unread.get('length') > 0;
    });
  })
});
```

And the template then uses the `hasUnreadNotifications` property to decide if the highlight class should be used:

```
<span class="icon">
  <i class="fa fa-bell {{if hasUnreadNotifications 'has-notifications'}}"></i>
</span>
```

---

However, it doesn't work. Although the store is called and notifications are returned, the `hadUnreadNotifications` doesn't resolve to a boolean. I think this is because it returns a promise and the template can't deal with that, but I'm not sure.

**Questions**

- Is it idiosyncratic ember to wrap the store in a service like this. I'm doing this because it feels clumsy to load the notifications in the application route just to show the count.
- Why doesn't `hasUnreadNotifications` return a boolean?
- Is it possible to make `read` and `unread` properties instead of functions, so a computed property can be created in the service to calculate the count?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Returning promise from computed property will not work. Computed properties are not Promise aware. to make it work you need to return DS.PrmoiseObject or DS.PromiseArray.

You can read other options available from this [igniter article](https://emberigniter.com/guide-promises-computed-properties/).

```
import Ember from 'ember';
import DS from 'ember-data';

export default Ember.Component.extend({
    notifications: Ember.inject.service(),
    session: Ember.inject.service(),

    hasUnreadNotifications: Ember.computed('notifications', function() {
        return DS.PromiseObject.create({
            promise: this.get('notifications').unread().then((unread) => {
                return unread.get('length') > 0;
            })
        });
    })

});
```